# How to track a value in SpringBoot after a being sent in httpResponse.sendError

Tags: java, spring-boot, localization

I'm trying to track down the origin of an variable, called "localizedMessage", which created in application code done on Spring boot.

I can track it as far as this statment:

```
httpResponse.sendError(status.value(), localizedMessage.trim());
```

in the following method

```
    private ErrorDTO handleException(Exception ex, HttpStatus status, WebRequest webRequest, String message,
            Object... messageArgs) {

        ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO(status, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex.getMessage());
        if (webRequest instanceof ServletWebRequest) {
            String localizedMessage = localizedMessageConverter.getLocalizedMessage(webRequest, message.trim(),
                    messageArgs);
            ServletWebRequest servletRequest = (ServletWebRequest) webRequest;
            HttpServletRequest request = servletRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = servletRequest.getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class);
            errorDTO.setUrl(request.getRequestURL().toString());
            try {
                httpResponse.sendError(status.value(), localizedMessage.trim());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        errorDTO.setStatus(status);
        errorDTO.setMessage(message);
        errorDTO.setError(ex.getMessage()
}
```

Here's what it says before:

```
Device(s) testPassword is (are) not configured properly. Proper connection settings are required for image server.
```

But somehow, it's getting modified after that statement. When viewed on the the display, it has

```
!!!image-servers:Device(s) testPassword is (are) not configured properly. Proper connection settings are required for image server.!!!
```

How do I find where the image is getting modified?

Comment: is your question where some "post-processor" might happen _after_ `handleException`?

Comment: you might want to check if you have an implementation of `ResponseBodyAdvice`?

Comment: Not much there - some jacco code in test. There are a lot of PostProcessors, but I don't see a match for validation. Tricky stuff!

Comment: @JackBeNimble: Can you try to generate Coorelation Id for every request that helps you to debug further. Here is the implementation of Coorelation Ids. https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-correlation-ids-0